# Suppose that n citizens of a town wish to form as many clubs as possible under the following rules:

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

**Suppose that n citizens of a town wish to form as many clubs as possible
under the following rules:**

**(a) each club should have an even number of members;**

**(b) each pair of clubs should have an odd number of members in com-
mon.**

**Show that the maximum possible number of clubs is n if n is odd and
n - 1 if n is even.**

I used linear algebra methods, but I can't work it out. Please help me.

Comment: Can you at least show that the given bounds can actually be achieved?

Comment: Also, can you share the source of this problem to show that it's not from an on-going contest? I don't normally answer PSQs but I had fun solving this one so I wouldn't mind giving you a hint, unless it's from a contest.

Comment: It's from our homework. I don't know how to prove it. A hint will be enough. :)

Answer (score 1):

I trust that if this was from a contest, you wouldn't have had the hint of using linear algebra.

So here is my hint: consider a matrix $M$ where each row corresponds to a club, and entry $m_{ij}$ is $1$ if Citizen $j$ is a member of Club $i$, and $0$ otherwise. This matrix is over the field $\Bbb F_2$. Then consider the augmented matrix $$\pmatrix{M &\matrix{1\\ \vdots\\ 1}\\ \matrix{1 & \cdots & 1}&0}$$